# CentOS Matplotlib RuntimeError: Could not open display

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, centos

I am using Cuda and run into a RuntimeError.

Environment:

```
Python 2.7
Cuda 9.0
Torch 0.4.0
Torchvision 0.1.8
Matplotlib 1.2.0
```

error message:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

Adding "MPLBACKEND=Agg" still outputs the above error message.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What is the result of `echo $DISPLAY`? Do you work remotely, did you switch the user?

Comment: Yes. I work remotely. `echo $DISPLAY` gives nothing. `lshw -C display` gives two displays. One is Nvidia's. My problem is actually solved via adding `import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')` before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I will close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I said that I would close this question. But since the answer might be interesting to some people, I leave it open. Maybe someone can explain to me why my solution worked?

I work remotely. `echo $DISPLAY` gives nothing. `lshw -C display` gives two displays. One is Nvidia's.

My problem is actually solved via adding

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're accessing another machine via `ssh`, make sure you log in using `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`.